# Elevation and depression, trigonometry.

Tags: trigonometry

A flagpole is mounted on top of a tall building. At a distance of $250$m from the base of the building, the angles of elevation of the bottom and the top of the flagpole are $38^\circ$ and $40^\circ$ respectively. Calculate the height of the flagpole, correct to one decimal place. Ok so I know the answer is $14.5$m, but I don't know how to solve it or do the working out? Why does the angle of elevation have $2$ angles, can someone please explain this problem? Thank you.

Comment: One angle of elevation is for the bottom of the flagpole, the second for the top of the flagpole.

Comment: I tried `250 Tan(40)` but that didn't work, what's the formula for this type of question?

Comment: $250 \tan 40^{\circ}$ is how high the __top__ of the flagpole to the ground.

Comment: Try for understanding - there is no formula to life...

Comment: `life = woman + man + intercourse` is a formula, which creates life

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $\,b=$ height of building, $\,f=$height of flag, then basic trigonometry gives

$$\tan 38^\circ=\frac b{250}\implies b=250\tan38^\circ\\{}\\
\tan40^\circ=\frac{f+b}{250}\implies f+b=250\tan40^\circ$$

and thus we get that

$$f=250(\tan40^\circ-\tan38^\circ)=14.453$$

Comment: This is great, thank you!

Comment: Is this the same to calculate the horizontal side and the hypotenuse?

Comment: Nop. From the viewer's point, you are calculating the tangent of the elevation angle by means of the opposite leg (the building's or the builidng + flag's height) and the adyacent leg (the distance between the viewer and the building $\;=250\;$ meter)

Comment: so what would be the formula for the other two sides?

Comment: What "other two sides"? You have two straight-angle triangles: one with its hypotenuse to the base of the flag's pole and the other one with its hypotenuse to the pole's top. Both have the same horizontal leg $\,250\,$, and one has the other leg the building whereas the other one hast the building + the flag as its other leg.

Comment: The common adjacent leg is 250 m (given), but there are two hypotenuses. Have you tried sketching a graph?

Comment: I mean for another problem, if I want to find the hypotenuse, or the length of the base, what would I use?

Comment: It all depends on what you are given. In this problem, for example, in order to find the hypotenuse, you could use cosine since you're given the elevation angle and the adyacent leg...

Comment: In the next question, the height is `500m`, The angles of depression are first 10(deg) and then 15(deg), find the horizontal side. What would I do here?

Comment: I\m sure that if you really think of this and check the answers you got here you can reach by yourself the answer. For example,  among other things, you could re-draw the diagram as to have elevation angles instead of depression ones...

Comment: I've tried everything to my knowledge after you suggested that, still got nothing, any other hints?

Comment: You should perhaps post another question

Comment: A news helicopter hovers at a height of `500m`. The angles of depression of a fire moving in the direction of the helicopter are first 10(deg) and then 15(deg), How far has the fire moved between thee two observations?

Comment: Post a **new** question

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467447/trigonometry-angles-of-depression thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Since the top of flagpole has an angle of elevation of $40^{\circ}$ and the horizontal distance is 250 m, find out how far is the **top** of flagpole above ground. Similarly, find out how far is the **bottom** of flagpole above ground.

Answer (score 0):

Let the tall building with the flag pole be a segment lying on the y-axis in $\mathbb R^2$. Its base is the origin $(0,0)$. We denote by

$$P=(250,0)$$

the point whose distance from the bottom of the building is $250$ meters.
We denote by $A$ the point corresponding to the bottom of the flagpole and by $B$ the one corresponding to the top of it, with

$$A=(0,y_1),$$
$$B=(0,y_2)$$

and $y_1<y_2$. The length of the flagpole is

$$l:=y_2-y_1.$$

Let us compute it; we know that

$$|AP|=\sqrt{250^2+y^2_1},$$
$$|BP|=\sqrt{250^2+y^2_2},$$

and

$$250=|AP|\cos(38^\circ),$$
$$250=|BP|\cos(40^\circ).$$

It follows that

$$250^2+y^2_1=\frac{250^2}{\cos^2(38^\circ)}\Rightarrow y_1=\sqrt{ \frac{250^2}{\cos^2(38^\circ) }-250^2}, $$
$$250^2+y^2_2=\frac{250^2}{\cos^2(40^\circ)}\Rightarrow y_2=\sqrt{\frac{250^2}{\cos^2(40^\circ)}-250^2}; $$

All you need now is to compute the difference

$$l=y_2-y_1=\sqrt{\frac{250^2}{\cos^2(40^\circ)}-250^2}- \sqrt{\frac{250^2}{\cos^2(38^\circ)}-250^2}.  $$

Comment: I think this process is unduly long and complex...after all it is basic trigonometry here. Yet it yields the correct answer.

Comment: probably it would have been better with a nice picture of the building and so.

Comment: I wonder why you chose not to use tangent.

Comment: nothing special behind my solution: I thought about it just like that...

Comment: And $\frac{250^2}{\cos^2 40^{\circ}}-250^2 = 250^2 \sec ^2 40^{\circ} - 250^2 = 250^2 \tan ^2 40^{\circ}$

Comment: Voila'@peterwhy, Q.E.D.