# Trigonometry, angles of depression.

Tags: trigonometry

A news helicopter hovers at a height of 500m. The angles of depression of a fire moving in the direction of the helicopter are first 10(deg) and then 15(deg), How far has the fire moved between thee two observations?

I know how to calculate the height if there was a base, thanks to another question I posted earlier, but how do I calculate the horizontal side? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the straight angle triangles: both have vertical leg equal to $\;500\;$, the upper angle and the end of this lef is $\,10^\circ\;$ (and for the other triangle it is $\,15^\circ\;$) , and you want the difference between both respective horizontal legs (on the floor).

If you have some problems doing that draw the resepctive diagrams and add them to your question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, sorry, can you please explain this as you explained my first question?

Comment: Draw the diagram(s) with letters and I'll tell you.

Comment: How do I draw them? I've never used this website before tonight.

Answer (score 0):

just draw the diagram and compare the cosines. you will get
the distance as $500(cos10 - cos15)$.
first draw the surface , then at some higher point a point where the helicopter is located , beneath that 2 points where the fires are seen and draw the angles

JUST IMAGINE......

Comment: I know that the answer is 970m, what do I do to get it?

Comment: Can you please just give me the working out?

Comment: ok iwill try to upload the diagram please wait.

Comment: iam not able to upload. con you just do what i say. take a fresh page then draw a horizontal line. do this and i will tell you the rest.

Comment: the closest i got, was 975m  by doing 500(cos15+cos10)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let x be the distance the fire has moved, and let y be the current distance from the fire to the point directly below the helicopter.  Then find $\cot 10 ^{\circ}$ and $\cot 15^{\circ}$ in terms of x and y, and solve for x.